# HTTP web request GET C#

Tags: c#, httprequest

I am trying to create HTTP Request to get the full html source with CSS styles. I already got the HTML source but without CSS styles ! , is there any other way to get full HTML with CSS styles ?

```
  // create an instance
            WebClient webClient = new WebClient();

            // call the HTML page you want to download, and get it as a string
            string htmlCode = webClient.DownloadString(uri);
            return htmlCode;
```

Comment: what you would like to achieve after getting the styles?

Comment: @Ramesh
Need to get elements that have by class !

Comment: The html will have all the classes, you don't requite the linked css files... Sorry, I am trying to understand your situation better.

Comment: @Ramesh

When I Inspect from browser I got the class = "section-result-header section-result-header-with-price" , but when I made http request I can't find this elements by class

Comment: It might so happen because those DOM elements are populated by javascript. When you use WebClient you will not execute any javascript. If you want to scrap the content, i would suggest selenium browser automation.

Answer (score 0):

Actually you can only get page text with "DownloadString" method. If css written in external file you can't get it.

Try this links:  With Css -    https://www.google.com/
Without Css - https://www.facebook.com/

In google head tags include some css and you can get them. But facebook don't.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to include the full css path of the website you trying to get the css content from for example :  www.data.com/css/stylex.css